# Consultas con DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server

Deseo retornar los siguientes valores como se muestra acontinuacion:

```
     fechaActual    Clave  Usuario  Depto   entrada     salida       sumaHoras
       201712       307    USER1   TTT      06:00:04  14:04:12          8
```

La consulta debe tomar la fecha actual del sistema y apartir de esta debe hacer el filtrado sin embargo; el resultado es distinto a la consulta de arriba, por un lado la suma es correcta pero no muestra la entrada y salida correcta, las salida que muestra las esta tomando apartir de lo que se encuentra definido en:

```
SELECT  @Hoy1 = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))+'00:00:00'
SELECT  @Hoy2 = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))+'23:59:59'.
```

Y también por que en la consulta se encuentra definida de esta forma:

```
  CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), @Hoy1,108) fechaEntrada,
  CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), @Hoy2,108) fechaSalida,
```

Consulta:

```
 DECLARE @Hoy DATETIME 
 DECLARE @Hoy1 DATETIME 
 DECLARE @Hoy2 DATETIME 

  SELECT  @Hoy = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))
  SELECT  @Hoy1 = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))+'00:00:00'
  SELECT  @Hoy2 = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))+'23:59:59'



select c.CodeCompany,
CONVERT(char(6), @Hoy, 112) AS fechaActual,
a.idClave,
c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos as Nombre,
d.Descripcion as Depto, 
CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), @Hoy1,108) fechaEntrada,
CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), @Hoy2,108) fechaSalida,
DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia
from tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto
where
   fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @Hoy1,103) and 
        CONVERT(DATETIME, @Hoy2,103)and fkStatus !=1
```

Resultado de la consulta

```
      fechaActual    Clave   Usuario   Depto                        entrada            salida           sumaHoras

              201712        10120      USER1      TTT                            00:00:00         23:59:59                8
```

Resultado deseado:

```
      fechaActual    Clave   Usuario   Depto                                    entrada            salida           sumaHoras                   201712       307    USER1   TTT                             06:00:04           14:04:12               8
```

Resultado incorrecto:

```
      fechaActual    Clave   Usuario   Depto                        entrada            salida           sumaHoras

                   201712        10120      USER1      TTT                            00:00:00         23:59:59                8
```

Comment: Las columnas _fechaEntrada_ y _fechaSalida_ estás considerando de la variable `@Hoy1` y `@Hoy2`, las cuales depende del `GETDATE()`. Por ende, nunca te saldría `06:00:04` y `14:04:12`. En tu consulta, la parte de `CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), @Hoy1,108) fechaEntrada`, estás utilizando `fechaEntrada` como alias, es lo mismo con `fechaSalida`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que el problema de las horas incorrectas en el resultado es simplemente que estás mostrando la hora de las variables `@Hoy1` y `@Hoy2` en lugar de los campos `fechaEntrada` y `fechaSalida`.

Por otro lado, si estás utilizando fechas y tienes los datos con tipo fecha, utilízalos así. No deberías andar convirtiendo las fechas a texto y de vuelta a fecha.... lo único que te va a generar es errores y problemas de rendimiento.

Tu consulta podría quedar algo así:

```
DECLARE @Hoy DATE
SELECT @Hoy = GETDATE()

SELECT c.CodeCompany, CONVERT(char(6), @Hoy, 112) AS fechaActual,
    a.idClave, c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos AS Nombre, d.Descripcion AS Depto, 
    CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), fechaEntrada, 108) fechaEntrada,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), fechaSalida, 108) fechaSalida,
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia
FROM tblasistencia a 
JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto
WHERE fechaEntrada BETWEEN @Hoy AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Hoy) and fkStatus !=1
```

Personalmente, incluso evitaría convertir a cadena el resultado de los campos. Si son datos de fecha devuélvelos como tal. Que sea la aplicación que reciba los datos y que quiera mostrarlos (en pantalla, informe,...) el que los formatee:

```
DECLARE @Hoy DATE
SELECT @Hoy = GETDATE()

SELECT c.CodeCompany, @Hoy AS fechaActual,
    a.idClave, c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos AS Nombre, d.Descripcion AS Depto, 
    fechaEntrada, fechaSalida,
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia
FROM tblasistencia a 
JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto
WHERE fechaEntrada BETWEEN @Hoy AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Hoy) and fkStatus !=1
```

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo formatear esta salida para que muestre solamente 05:55:24.000 y no fecha y hora 2018-01-04 05:55:24.000?

Comment: Si únicamente quieres la hora podrías convertirlo a tipo `TIME`: `CONVERT(TIME, fechaEntrada)`

Comment: No sé si es correcto el caso es que deseo visualizar la hora y los minutos, asi: 05:58.
Con CONVERT(TIME, fechaEntrada) el resultado es de esta forma:

Comment: 05:58:50.8900000
Y si lo convierto a char, de esta forma:
  convert(char(6), fechaEntrada,108) AS Entrada
Entonces puedo maniobrar cuantos caracteres deseo visualizar con char(6) lo muestra asi:05:58

Comment: Puedes hacerlo así, pero como te comentaba en la respuesta, yo formatearía los datos en el momento de mostrarlos (en pantalla, web, informe....), no en la consulta. Pero es una opinión personal. El formato en el que mostrar la hora es un detalle de presentación que yo no incluiría nunca en una consulta.

Comment: ok. Cuando agregas DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Hoy) ,
agregas un día más?

En la consulta: BETWEEN @Hoy AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Hoy)
se toma el día actual hasta el otro día.
o toma hasta las 23:59 del mismo día.

Comment: Se toma desde el día actual a las 00:00 hasta el día siguiente a las 00:00

Comment: Hay alguna forma de especificar que solo sea des las 00:00 hasta las 23:59
es decir: BETWEEN @Hoy AND @HOY+'23:59:59' Sin tener que pasarnos al siguiente día

Comment: Ten en cuenta que con esa condición únicamente entraría una entrada del día siguiente si la hora fuese exactamente las 00:00:00.000. Pero si crees que puede darse el caso puedes utilizar otros comparadores: `fechaEntrada >= @Hoy AND fechaEntrada < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Hoy)`. De esta forma evitas esa posibilidad.

Comment: Ok.Muchas gracias,